# Lenovo Flex 14 Fingerprint Sensor in Ubuntu

Tags: lenovo, fingerprint-reader, additional-drivers

I recently bought a Lenovo Flex 14 and installed Ubuntu 18.04 on it. This computer has a fingerprint sensor and I want to be able to use it in Ubuntu. I have tried FPrint and Fingerprint GUI but both didn't recognize my scanner. Is there another application that will recognize my scanner?

```
~$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 27c6:55b4  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:56b2 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your device is a Goodix Fingerprint sensor. Currently there is no driver for this device in Linux.

Dell is working with Goodix to provide drivers for some of their sensors that are used in Dell laptops and they said they will try to support a few other models too (using a closed source driver). Maybe your device will get a driver in future. Also there is an open issue about this device in libfprint repository:

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues/173

---

**Edit (November 2022):**

We now have an experimental driver for this device. It is based on the libfprint project and the [SIGFM](https://github.com/mpi3d/sigfm) matching algorithm.

There is an [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libfprint-goodixtls-55x4) package for Arch users. Ubuntu users can build it from the source:

https://github.com/TheWeirdDev/libfprint/tree/55b4-experimental